# Call to undefined function SocialiteProviders\Patreon\array_get()

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-6

I have just updated the laravel framework from 5.8.35 to 6.0.3.

Everything mostly works except for SocialiteProviders/Patreon which causes the following error when authenticating

```
Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError thrown with message "Call to undefined function SocialiteProviders\Patreon\array_get()"

Stacktrace:
#1 Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError in /var/www/html/vendor/socialiteproviders/patreon/Provider.php:67
#0 {main} in /var/www/html/public/index.php:0
```

Comment: Thanks for this information. Hopefully we get an update soon!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So after some time i managed to solve this before posting this question so im posting it anyway with how i solved it

Turns out the SocialiteProviders/Patreon package hasn't had a release done in a while but the code to fix this is already on the master branch

So editing the version number in `composer.json` file to

```
"socialiteproviders/patreon": "dev-master#0cd961b7d618a52bca86c4dd91c2dcb7a59df297"
```

and then running

```
composer update
```

solved my issue. Hope this helps others